# Grabbing a parent of a certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a sliding mini menu. I'm trying to do it using jquery. Basically, I need to grab the h2 element that is in a certain box.

https://jsfiddle.net/1nksxhe0/2/

It yelled at me to add code here, so I'm adding the main JS function, but it makes more sense to put it on jsfiddle

```
$('.category-button').on('click', function () {
$(this).closest('h2').css('color','yellow');
});
```

For example, if I click the see the videos button under animation I want only the Animation h2 to light up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The H2 element isn't a parent of the button, your markup is as follows

```
<h2 class="col-md-12 text-center category-title">Self Promotion </h2>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <a target="_blank" href="url">
        <button id="..." type="button" class="btn category-button">See The Videos</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Meaning you want the closest DIV, then the previous H2

```
$('.category-button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').prev('h2').css('color','yellow');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1nksxhe0/4/)

Comment: Assuming your `h2` will always be just before the `div` that contains the button, of course.

Comment: @TLS - Yes, assuming the OP doesn't change the HTML linked to in the question, then all bets are off anyway.

Comment: That's the html I want to use. Is there any way to make the code more change endurable though? Just curious

Comment: As it's traversing the DOM to find the elements, it relies on the DOM being the way it is. There aren't really many ways to change that, if you change the DOM, the DOM traversal has to change as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('h2').css('color', 'yellow');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1nksxhe0/3/

Comment: Can't I use closest() or something like that? To make the code more editable? Ok, never mind. I just read other responses